# Como gerar um arquivo XML à partir de um formulário em PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Fiz o seguinte formulário:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="cadastro.php">
         Informacoes <br>
         Nome <input type="text" name="nome"> <br>
         Endereco <input type="text" name="endereco"> <br>
         <input type="submit" name="insert" value="add">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

E queria saber como posso fazer para gravar isso em um arquivo XML. Tipo:

```
<exemplo>
    <cadastro>
        <nome>
            Nome Sobrenome
        </nome>
        <endereco>
            Rua tal
        </endereco>
    </cadastro>
</exemplo>
```

Qualquer exemplo é bem vindo, quero entender como faz mas não acho nenhum exemplo direito na web, agradeço.

Testei o código para pegar as variáveis do cadastro e ficou assim:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

if (isset($_POST['botao'])){

#versao do encoding xml
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");

#retirar os espacos em branco
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

#gerar o codigo
$dom->formatOutput = true;

#criando o nó principal (root)
$root = $dom->createElement("agenda");

#nó filho (contato)
$contato = $dom->createElement("contato");

#setanto nomes e atributos dos elementos xml (nós)
$nome = $dom->createElement("nome", $nome);
$email = $dom->createElement("email", $email);
$telefone = $dom->createElement("telefone", $telefone);

#adiciona os nós (informacaoes do contato) em contato
$contato->appendChild($nome);
$contato->appendChild($email);
$contato->appendChild($telefone);

#adiciona o nó contato em (root) agenda
$root->appendChild($contato);
$dom->appendChild($root);

# Para salvar o arquivo, descomente a linha
$dom->save("contatos.xml");

#cabeçalho da página
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
# imprime o xml na tela
print $dom->saveXML();

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue o código:

```js
<?php
#versao do encoding xml
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");

#retirar os espacos em branco
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

#gerar o codigo
$dom->formatOutput = true;

#criando o nó principal (root)
$root = $dom->createElement("agenda");

#nó filho (contato)
$contato = $dom->createElement("contato");

#setanto nomes e atributos dos elementos xml (nós)
$nome = $dom->createElement("nome", "Rafael Clares");
$telefone = $dom->createElement("telefone", "(11) 5500-0055");
$endereco = $dom->createElement("endereco", "Av. longa n 1");

#adiciona os nós (informacaoes do contato) em contato
$contato->appendChild($nome);
$contato->appendChild($telefone);
$contato->appendChild($endereco);

#adiciona o nó contato em (root) agenda
$root->appendChild($contato);
$dom->appendChild($root);

# Para salvar o arquivo, descomente a linha
//$dom->save("contatos.xml");

#cabeçalho da página
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
# imprime o xml na tela
print $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Ele gera o seguinte XML:

```html
<agenda>
<contato>
<nome>Rafael Clares</nome>
<telefone>(0xx11) 5500-0055</telefone>
<endereco>Av. Longa n 1</endereco>
</contato>
</agenda>
```

[Esse exemplo](http://blog.clares.com.br/gerando-xml-com-php/) é bem fácil de ver.

Espero ter ajudado.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Segue o [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/72re-kuqu) com o código da pergunta, forçando o `if` com `true`.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32088/discussion-on-answer-by-ricardo-como-gerar-um-arquivo-xml-a-partir-de-um-formula)